# FoxyProxy substitute for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, foxyproxy

I don't have direct network access to the linux host I'm debugging PHP/Javascript code on.  I SSH to a jump box, then use FoxyProxy to tunnel my firefox requests through my SSH session using SOCKS forwarding.

I want to be able to debug the javascript code in IE, but unfortunately my FoxyProxy setup only works through the FireFox extension.  Is there a quick and dirty solution that will allow me to tunnel my web traffic (for certain hosts!) through a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SOCKS forwarding and IE, use [FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/?p=download). Enables pretty much any application to use a SOCKS proxy, is free (as in beer) and reliable (even allows proxy chaining).

Comment: FoxyProxy will automatically route traffic through different proxies for you based on wildcard patterns and whitelist/blacklist rules.  Does FreeCap have anything similar? (I think that's what the question was)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved using Fiddler, steps are mentioned below Download and install Fiddler from telerik.com/download/fiddler. Open Fiddler, Go to AutoResponder tab Check 'Enable Rules' and 'Unmatched requests passthrough' checkboxes. Click on 'Add Rule' button and add your rule/s